# How to make automated Voice call application in php?

Tags: php, voice-recording, voice-recognition

I want to make a automated call application, which will dial some mobile numbers, and give the response to them, and also record there voice in wave and text format. is it possible in PHP, or there is any buildin function or classes for doing that?

Comment: Please ask more specific questions. "How can I make this or that application?" is a topic for a book, not a question that can really be answered here.

Comment: i am sorry...@ Techpriester...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/), they have [PHP support](https://www.tropo.com/docs/scripting/samples-php.htm).

Comment: can i connect it through my database??

Comment: You need some glue code to pipe your data through, but you can access the API from your server (so yes, you can use your database).

Comment: is there any example for using Tropo WebAPI in PHP??

Comment: Somewhere on the site probably, I don't use PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[ribbit](http://developer.ribbit.com/)
 offers an API for making calls, playing files, etc ([php link](http://developer.ribbit.com/development-center/php/php-center))

Comment: is ribbit free like tropo, i wass using tropo but the problem is that it is not that flexible as i wanted all the data input from user to be saved in my database...

Comment: i have not used ribbit...i have used tropo, which i found little bit easy... thank u @Dan Heberden..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) and implement an IVR flow using [AGI php scripts](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI+php).

Asterisk is an open source telephony project. You install the software on a linux box, then you connect some phone lines (PSTN, ISDN, SIP, whatever).

Asterisk can be controlled by using AGI php scripts to build custom interactions (dial number XXX, play wave "Press one to do this, two to do that", read DTMF input from user, etc).

Comment: thank u @diciu...i have not used asterisk... i am using tropo..as it is bit easy for me to understand....hence i selected the above answer....

Comment: Hi, I have checked out Asterisks but I'm not sure it's what I need. I didn't fully comprehend it but it think it's for bug companies. I just need a voice call notification system. Not too different from basic SMS notification and not more than 10 seconds. Please how do i go about this? If asterisk is not ideal service for me, what else can i use?